# Math in jQuery: adding 2 variables math value together and then outputting them in HTML

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to take 2 variables, perform math on them and then output them as a new 3rd variable.  Here's the basic logic I attempting to do:

```
var A1 = [+ditto_iteration+]
var B1 = [+gallery_currentPage+]
var C1 = (B1-1)*3+A1+1
```

Then I need to take the value of the variable C and output in some HTML like so:

```
<a href="variable C1 here">link</a>
```

So to clarify, I've got some programming that will output the value of [+ditto_iteration+] on page load.  Same with [+gallery_currentPage+].  I just need to be able to take the variable values of A1 and B1, perform the math as shown above and then replace a variable in the URL (in this case C1) with the resulting value of the math operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script>
var A1 = parseInt([+ditto_iteration+]);
var B1 = parseInt([+gallery_currentPage+]);
var C1 = (B1-1)*3+A1+1;

$('#link').attr('href', C1);

</script>


<a id='link' href="variable C1 here">link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<a id="replaceMe" href="variable C1 here">link</a>
```

and your jQuery:

```
$('#replaceMe').attr('href',C1);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/whQ5v/

After reading the title I was tempted to post this naked link:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif

Answer (score 1):

```
var A1 = 10,
    B1 = 30,
    C1 = (B1 - 1) * 3 + A1 + 1;

$('a').attr('href', C1).text('C1 value is ' + C1);
```

Live here [http://jsfiddle.net/q3EL3](http://jsfiddle.net/q3EL3/)

Answer (score 0):

if you give the  element an id like so:

```
<a id="c1val" href="variable C1 here">link</a>
```

you can do it much easier.

With the id attribute

```
$("a#c1val").attr("href",C1 + ''); //Adding empty string makes C1 a string
```

Without the id attribute (only works once)

```
$('a[href="variable C1 here"]').attr("href",C1 + ''); //Adding empty string makes C1 a string
```